# Expand column which has list and date in power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a column which has a list of dates and dates.

[image]

[image]
I need to expand the column so that the list of dates under list gets expanded along with the dates in the column.

I have used the below code and getting the "Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Table.
Details:
Value=[List]
Type=[Type]"

`Table.TransformColumns([Custom],{{[Custom],each if Value.Is(_,type list) then _ else {_}}})`

Code to generate the list

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Blank Rows", "New end date", each let StDt = [#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"],
```

Code to expand the list as per your code.

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Table.TransformColumns([New end date]{{[New end date],each if Value.Is(_,type list) then _ else {_}}}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This converts non-list rows to lists so that the arrow option shows up

```
x = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepName", {{"Custom", each if Value.Is(_, type list) then _ else {_} }} )
```

then use the arrows atop the column to expand. Then change type

Before picture:

[image]

after picture

[image]

full sample code

```
let Source =  #table({"a"}, {{"10/1/2020"},{"4/1/2020"},{"6/1/2020"},{"1/1/2020"},{"10/4/2020"},{"10/8/2020"}}),
z = {"5/31/2021","5/15/2020","3/14/2019"},
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Index]<2 then z else [a], type any),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
// prior is just to set up sample data
x = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {{"Custom", each if Value.Is(_, type list) then _ else {_} }} ),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(x, "Custom"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Custom", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Table.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]

Comment: Show what is inside your list by clicking on it and showing the bottom half of the preview screen

Comment: I have updated the screenshot now.

Comment: show your code from home ... advanced editor ...  our inputs match exactly so there should be no difference

Comment: Putting code in a comment is a terrible idea.  That said, the code you added has nothing to do with your question, and does not contain the code I suggested you try here.  Use my full code sample above, and compare to whatever you are doing to find whats different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243714/discussion-between-user17295743-and-horseyride).

Comment: I have updated the code which i replicated using your code and i'm still getting the "Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Table."

Comment: Hey,, sorry man - I'm getting the error "Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?"